# Trying to run PHP code with Coldfusion on cfgroovy

Tags: php, coldfusion, lucee

I know the cfgroovy seems to be dead project, but i am trying to run the php code on the cfgroovy but it is not working, if i run a PHP code in my xampp server, it works good, but when i run that php code inside cfgroovy, i get an invalid: nonce error

here is my code inside cfgroovy

and the php code is this:

https://github.com/payward/kraken-api-client

and here is my code in CF using cfgroovy, i installed the latest querbus JAr file in the coldfusion directory to make it work

```
<cftry>
   <g:script lang="php">
      <?php 
        $key = 'APIKEY';
        $secret = 'APISECRET';
        $request = array();
        if(!isset($request['nonce'])) {
            $nonce = explode(' ', microtime());
            $request['nonce'] = $nonce[1] . str_pad(substr($nonce[0], 2, 6), 6, '0');
        }

        $pspostdata = http_build_query($request, '', '&');

        $variables["postdata"] = $request['nonce'] . $pspostdata;

        $version = '0';
        $method = 'TradeBalance';

        $path = '/' . $version . '/private/' . $method;
        $sign = hash_hmac('sha512', $path . hash('sha256', $variables["postdata"] . $pspostdata, true), base64_decode($secret), true);
        $variables["myArray"] = base64_encode($sign); 

        $headers = array(
            'API-Key: ' . $key,
            'API-Sign: ' . base64_encode($sign)
        );

        $cl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($cl, array(
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Kraken PHP API Agent',
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true)
        );

        // make request
        curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.kraken.com' . $path);
        curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $pspostdata);
        curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        $variables["results"] = curl_exec($cl);

        // decode results
        //$variables["myArray"] = json_decode($variables["results"], true);
      ?>
   </g:script>
   <cfhttp url="https://api.kraken.com/0/private/TradeBalance" method="POST" result="result">
      <cfhttpparam name="API-Key" type="HEADER"  value="#key#">
      <cfhttpparam name="API-Sign" type="HEADER"  value='#variables["myArray"]#'>
    </cfhttp>
    <cfdump var="#variables#">
    <cfdump var="#result#">
```

error i am getting is this

https://prnt.sc/xibngw

i narrowed down the problem and this seems to be an issue

```
hash_hmac('sha512', $path . hash('sha256', $request['nonce'] . $postdata, true), base64_decode($this->secret), true);
```

with the jar i downloaded and the xampp which is being used, i am using using xampp version 3.3.2

mine is: xampp : 7.025 and querbus jar works with 5.4.0 - if i had either fix the hash_hmac function, how can i do in php version 5.4.0 or i coldfusion

Comment: (1) I can't find any posts re: `cfgroovy` after 2009. (2) That Kraken API hasn't been updated in 6 years. (3) I can only find this regarding `PHP in Java`: http://quercus.caucho.com/ (4) What version of CF are you using? (5) What version of Java? (6) What are you trying to accomplish? (7) Java has an `HMAC` implementation that could be used instead.